# Adding limit on when to add data for a specific object

Tags: c#

So I have a simple app that accepts bookings, and for a specific location, there's a maximum no. of people allowed.

i.e: Location1 only 5 people allowed, Location2 only 3 people allowed.

However, the thing is all the bookings are added in a single list so I had to check it using this.

```
foreach(var foo in MyList)
if (foo.destinationName == "Location1")
count++
```

The code above counts how many bookings in the list for location 1 already and I do the same for checking Location2, now on my CanExecute statement, I do this

```
if(CheckLocation1Booking() == 5 || CheckLocation2Booking() == 2)
{
deny adding of booking
}
```

However, it will fail if Location1 has 5 bookins already even though location2 still has none, any workaround pls on the if statement? Thank you!

Comment: If you want both the conditions to be true for `deny adding of booking` then  you should use `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: Tried that, however, if location1 is 5 but location2 is 0, it will still allow adding to location1, any workarounds?

Comment: `it will still allow adding to location1,` where is this happening? you code doesn't have anything for this..

Comment: there's an else statement following that where it adds a new element to the list.

Comment: I think I am not able to grasp the logic you want implement... you want to deny booking for if location1 == 5 and location2 == 2. But you also want to deny booking if location2==0..? isn't it contradicting? You might want to go back to the board and draw a logical flow you want and then translate it to code

Comment: Oh sorry, let me explain this clearly. For example, if location1 has 5 bookings already but location2 still has none, the program should allow the users to create a BOOKING to location2 but deny on location1. Adding && in the IF STATEMENT will allow the program to add a new booking to location1 even though the limit of "5" bookings have been reached already. This is where I'm stuck. The same goes for the other way round.

Comment: My 2 cents: `var countLocationOne = MyList.Count(e=> e.destinationName == "Location1");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate the checks out using code similar to the below:

```
bool allowLocation1 = CheckLocation1Booking() == 5;
bool allowLocation2 = CheckLocation2Booking() == 2;

if (allowLocation1)
    // Add to Location 1
else if (allowLocation2)
    // Add to Location 2
```

Comment: I could do that, however, the list containing all the bookings is only one. :/

Comment: Not sure how that affects the above. Simply add a new item to MyList with the required location name. So if allowLocation1 - add an item with destinationName == Location1.

Comment: Hi Gary, I forgot to say that it will be based on user input, so how may I go about that? I have a binding from the textbox in the View.

Comment: Nvm, got it now :)